# Trouble deploying app from Ubuntu SDK to phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, nexus-4

I'm trying to run the App with Simple UI template on Nexus 4 but I'm getting these warnings

Under Issues

```
warning: desktop_Exec (app): found unexpected Exec with architecture 'all': ./qtc_device_debughelper.py
warning: security_policy_groups_safe_app (debug): (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use
The debug policy group is automatically injected and should only be used for development. To create a package for the store use the publish tab!
```

Under Application Output

```
Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:10000' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Sdk-Launcher> Executing:     /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.username.helloworldtest_0.1_all.click
Sdk-Launcher> Force Install: False
Sdk-Launcher> Skip Uninstall:False
Sdk-Launcher> Launcher PID: 3831
Sdk-Launcher> Installing application .....
Failed to parse command line: Unknown option --allow-untrusted
Sdk-Launcher> Installing the application failed
```

I have trusty proposed installed on the Nexus 4 and I created an armhf 14.04 kit. The SDK does seem to detect the device properly from under options,devices.

I've had this working before, I'm not sure what is wrong now. I just reinstalled everything but nothing changed/helped.

EDIT:

Just put 14.10 on Nexus 4 and made a 14.10 kit. The helloworld app ran without any problems, could this be a 14.04 specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

First ensure the USB Cable is working correctly and try to connect it directly without a USB HUB.

Then on Ubuntu Touch go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>About this phone</kbd>. Then go all the way to the bottom <kbd>Developer Mode</kbd>, set a <kbd>Lock security</kbd> to your liking and then **turn on** <kbd>Developer Mode</kbd>